# Homebrew and house-rules tag - community seems to be using them wrong, what to do?

Tags: discussion

So, we have a [meta discussion](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5845/43856) on the distinction between [house-rules](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/house-rules) and [homebrew](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homebrew). Fine for me, that's exactly how I understood them. But we have some (good amount) of questions tagged wrongly.

As a few examples, these questions are tagged as Homebrew but (at least for me) are actually about House Rules:

- [Asks about house ruling putting manacles on resisting characters](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/123869/43856).
- [I'm not sure what this is](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/123315/43856). - This is adding an extra feature to the Paladin Class. Is this a house rule or could be read as homebrewing a "new class" (or a new feature for an existing class)?

On the other hand, these questions are tagged as House Rules but are actually about Homebrew.

- [Homebrew feat](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/121656/43856).
- [Homebrew weapon](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/122878/43856).
- [Homebrew ranger subclass](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/122706/43856).

Admittedly, it seems that the House Rules tag is used for Homebrew more often (and clearly) than the opposite.

So, **what do we do about it?** Simply edit every question tagged wrongly? To be fair, **do we even need two tags for that?**

Comment: So I'll own up to actually changing the [weapon](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/122878/43856) question from homebrew to houserule. In retrospect I should have left it as is. I was focusing more on the application of the rule to the weapon than the weapon itself. But I think the weapon is actually the cause for the question and therefore [tag:homebrew] is more appropriate. It is worth noting that OP actually tagged it correctly to begin with however.

Comment: Also, though this might be a lot of work, I think that having some idea of *how often* the terms are misused would lend a lot more weight behind the idea that there is a problem here. It is easy to pull a few instances of misuse from almost any tag (though I think there is more confusion around these two than most for sure).

Comment: @Rubiksmoose I'm not sure how (or even if) we can do that. In particular, as our policy is to actually fix it as mxyzplk answer notes, we would have to look into edit history and check how each question was created. I agree that we have misuses on more tags, but it seems a great part of the community sees these tags as the same. See [this comment](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/123869/how-do-i-adjudicate-attempting-to-put-manacles-on-an-unwilling-creature?noredirect=1#comment305701_123869) for example.

Comment: I have to say, that even after reading the meta discussions, I'm not clear on the difference between "homebrewing new rules content" and "creating house rules". It's also not clear whether the tags are supposed to indicate something about desired answers, or whether they're to help clarify something about the question.

Comment: @PeterCooperJr. My understanding on tags is that none of your readings is correct actually. They are not meant to indicate anything about the answers. You could read it as clarifying the question, but it seems more about classifying the questions than clarifying them. If I look for [tag:dnd-5e] I know I'm looking only for questions about D&D 5e. If I search [tag:gm-techniques], I know I will be finding only questions about the DM side - not the player side. etc. That's my current view on tags on this site.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, we need both, per [What distinction is being drawn between house-rules and homebrew?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5845/what-distinction-is-being-drawn-between-house-rules-and-homebrew).

As usual if someone misuses a tag, you should edit, comment, etc. to address the error, as applicable for your rep level.