# When is the Houserule tag appropriate?

Tags: discussion, tags

Based on [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/119661/will-an-electrum-shortsword-do-bonus-damage-against-lycanthropic-creatures) I have an unclear understanding of when and how to use the Houserule and Homebrew tags.

Homebrew tag has some clearer guidance:

> For questions about homebrewing new rules content for an existing system

That seems to be imply the tag is for when you are creating, or homebrewing, new content and asking about it's balance, etc. If that is incorrect, we should probably change that language.

Houserules tag states:

> House rules are small fan created additions and replacements to core rules in a rules set. In most cases, they are not officially sanctioned by the designer, in contrast to optional rules.

Unlike Homebrew, this tag does not talk specifically about "homebrewing new rules", but instead seems to be more general.

If we return to the question cited above, it is unclear to me as to whether or not the House-rules tag should be included.

The question is asking how a house-rule item, the Electrum Shortsword, and how it interacts with the existing rules regarding Lycanthropes.

My concern is that because the item is a non-standard item and was house-ruled in creation, we can *try* to answer based on the existing rules but that any true answer needs to understand the specifics of the house-ruled item and the house ruled tag *should* be included.

All in all, when a houseruled/homebrewed item is being discussed and a question revolves around it's interaction with existing rules should the house-rules tag be included as an identifier for the querent and answerers?

Comment: Related: [What distinction is being drawn between house-rules and homebrew?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5845/23970), [Differentiating between House rules, Homebrew and and game design](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1219/23970)

Comment: I think this might be a duplicate of [What distinction is being drawn between house-rules and homebrew?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5845/what-distinction-is-being-drawn-between-house-rules-and-homebrew)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I don't think it's a dupe - that a differentiation question and mine is a question on when to apply. They are absolutely related, though.

Answer (score 7):

Drawing on [What distinction is being drawn between house-rules and homebrew?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5845/what-distinction-is-being-drawn-between-house-rules-and-homebrew), [house-rules](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/house-rules) is used when there are locally-created **rules** at the core of the question. This is as opposed to [homebrew](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homebrew), which is when locally-created **content** is at the heart of the question.

In the case of the magic electrum sword, the sword itself is content, ergo [homebrew](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homebrew). If there are additional rules created by that group about how *that* sword functions, that's still homebrew content — unique effects generally don't rise to the level of house rules, they're just part of the new content.

If that group generally uses added rules for electrum weaponry, magical and mundane, that would be house rules and would merit [house-rules](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/house-rules). (I don't see any question content about house rules there though.)

Comment: So the question in question should be [tag:homebrew]?

Comment: @NautArch I think there are already more important tags taking up the 5 tag slots. The problem in the question is less about the sword and its "homebrew-ness" and more about how lycanthropy works, so though [[tag:homebrew]] could fit, I don't think it's even necessary in that specific case.

Comment: Gotcha- and the question clearly was about a misunderstanding on immunity vs vulnerability, but I was unsure because the weapon in question was homebrew and could have riders we don't know about (but have to make assumptions about in order to really answer). But I don't see how "special-materials" is any more or less relevant than homebrew, either.

Comment: But I think we should update the tag info to reflect your answer if that is the agreement. The way it's presented now in the info isn't clear.

Comment: @NautArch It could be a bit clearer. Some of the wording in [that other meta](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5845/what-distinction-is-being-drawn-between-house-rules-and-homebrew) might be useful to incorporate.

Comment: I added some of that info from your answer here and the top answer on the linked question to the tags.