# Is this question better tagged house-rules or homebrew?

Tags: discussion, tags, questions, homebrew

I am considering a revision to the D&D 5e mechanics of maintaining barbarian rage.  I consider this to be a small change to a *specific rule* and thus fitting of the [house-rules](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/house-rules) tag, rather than [homebrew](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homebrew) tag, which is reserved for larger changes to *rule systems*.

However, my point in posting the question would be to solicit review of the potential impacts and interactions with the rule change.  While there is a [homebrew-review](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homebrew-review) tag for such questions, there does not appear to be a corresponding "house rules review" tag.

Which tag is more appropriate for my question and why?

Related: [Differentiating between house rules, homebrew, and game design](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1219/differentiating-between-house-rules-homebrew-and-and-game-design)

More related: [What distinction is being drawn between house-rules and homebrew?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5845/what-distinction-is-being-drawn-between-house-rules-and-homebrew)

---

Update: The question has now been asked here: [Would allowing barbarians to maintain rage as an action be unbalanced or permit shenanigans?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/197443/23547)

Comment: Somewhat related: "[Do we want a \[homebrew-review\] tag separate from the \[homebrew\] tag?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9149)"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [house-rules](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/house-rules) [tag description](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tags/house-rules/info) states (emphasis mine):

> A rules set strives to be complete, but no set of rules covers every circumstance. Rules that are fan-driven and implemented unofficially are termed house rules. Contrast with optional-rules, which are officially created additional rules.
>
> House-Rules are for new or modified rules. Whether it's creating rules to cover situations that aren't handled by RAW or customizing existing rules ("we don't use the RAW grappling rules, because they're stupid"), house rules modify the framework of the system.
>
> House rules can completely replace certain parts of the rules set, or merely add to the existing rules to make them more complex, complete, and/or well-rounded. Many times they are created in response to a need that the designers overlooked. But just as often, they are created to take the game in a direction fitting to a certain campaign.
>
> **This tag should be used to discuss implementation, effects, and/or changes engendered by the use of house rules in the basic rules set.**
>
> GMs make table-specific rulings about how the rules work all the time; these aren't generally considered house rules unless they're codified and used consistently.
>
> **For questions about substantial new material** (e.g., whole classes, monsters, etc.) or new subsystems (e.g., adding detailed crafting or chase rules), **use the homebrew tag instead.**

You have used the correct tags.